# Limit the number of posts a wordpress author can post. (PHP, wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Situation:

There are a total of 3 packages:

1. a package that will allow authors to post 15 posts.
2. a package that will allow authors to post 50 posts.
3. a package that allows unlimited posts.

The posts should not be limited to a specific day. It's about the total posts allowed.
Note that the role of the users are all authors.

What would be the best approach to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a plugin called 'Post creation limits'.

This isn't an ideal solution because you have to manually find the user ID and restrict that to a specified post limit.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is callad "Bainternet Posts Creation Limits" and you can download it here for free:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/

I have tested it and it works with the latest WP version

You can limit posts of any type to a group of users by rolls.
So basically, you need a few seconds to set it up and enjoy.

p.s. you might use this plugin also (to control your members):
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

Cheers!
Vjeko